# Can't install boost-python on macos

Tags: python, macos, boost

Upon running `brew install boost-python` I get the error:

```
Error: boost-python has been disabled because it does not build!
```

and nothing else. What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: `boost-python` may need C/C++ library `boost` and this may need C/C++ compiler to compile/build it. Compilation may need also Python's C/C++ headers - file `.h` - which on Linux Ubuntu/Mint/Debian I would install with `apt install python-dev` but I don't know how to install it on other systems. It can't be installed with `pip`